# method in React component class is not identified

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a simple ReactJS component class as below. This class is written inside a .jsx file.

```
class ListOfUsers extends Component {



    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            listOfUsersReport: []
        };
        this.getReportParameter = this.getReportParameter.bind(this);

    }

    componentWillMount() {
                             //error is coming from below line: getReportParameter() call
        this.fetchLocation('reportingrest/reportRequest/reportDefinition/d3950d7c-4881-11e7-a919-92ebcb67fe33', this.getReportParameter())
            .then((response) => {
                console.log('response from openmrs server : ' + response);
                this.setState({ listOfUsersReport: response });
            });


    }

    getReportParameter() {
        return {
            "retired": "false"
        };
    }

    fetchLocation(url, paramData) {
        const apiHelper = new ApiHelper(null);
        const getData = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            apiHelper.post(url, paramData).then(response => {
                response.json().then(data => {
                    resolve(data);
                });
            });
        });
        return getData;
    }

    render() {


        return (
            <h1>
                records fetched size: {this.state.listOfUsersReport.dataSets.rows}
            </h1>
        );
    }

}

export default ListOfUsers;
```

When I try to load my app, I am getting the following error in my browser console.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: getReportParameter is not defined
```

Comment: `this.getReportParameter = this.getReportParameter.bind(this)` I don't understand. it makes sense when called inside JSX tags but inside the class constructor I don't think it makes sense.

Comment: Try a [fat arrow](https://medium.com/komenco/react-autobinding-2261a1092849) function instead, it automatically binds so you wont have to in the constructor:
```constructor() {
    super();
        this.state = {
            listOfUsersReport: []
        };
}

getReportParameter = () => {
  // same logic
}
```

Comment: @Reyraa even without that line, it didn't work

Comment: This doesn't make sense, I cannot see how it would error unless you have omitted/edited some key code

Comment: Don't make Api calls in `componentWillMount ` as stated [here](https://daveceddia.com/where-fetch-data-componentwillmount-vs-componentdidmount/).  and try `ListOfUsers . getReportParameter ` instead. hope it works

Comment: @Reyraa binding methods in the constructor is very common practice. its in the official docs even https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/handling-events.html